# Disable touch events of activity except back button of action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, touch-event

I know how to disable touch events of activity, but I want only back button of action bar should be touchable while whole activity is disabled.
Is there any way in android to do this?

I use this line to disable touch events

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE)
```